# Identify annotation class in java

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a utility that scans different classes in the classpath, and checks for unused classes.

Some classes need special treatment, like interfaces and abstract classes. Those can be easily identified using reflection.
The problem arises when trying to identify a class that is an annotation class (i.e. @interface).
Is it possible to know if a class is really an annotation?

Comment: try it with    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAnnotation%28%29

Comment: above comment can help you, also notice this: Returns true if this Class object represents an annotation type. Note that if this method returns true, isInterface() would also return true, as all annotation types are also interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, the isAnnotation() worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah.. It's possible to know if a class is really an annotation.
Please try this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAnnotation%28%29

http://java.dzone.com/articles/discovering-java-annotations

It may help you